# Concurrency of lines formed by pair of circles joining pairwise.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

How can i prove that lines $AD,EB,CF$ are concurrent ?[image]

**My attempt**
[image]

Considering $\Delta ACB$ I've got the condition that $\cfrac {CP \cdot BQ \cdot AR}{PB \cdot AQ \cdot RC}=1 $ ,but I don't see how can I apply this condition since I don't see how to get those ratios.

Playing with a weaker version of the problem,namely with 3 circles where two of them are congruent ,I see that the above condition is applicable since every of the above  lengths,like $CP$ and $RC$ , are in ratio $1$ ,therefore it's easy to prove the concurrency of lines.So it's obvious  that I am not looking for the right pattern,the kind of pattern which is applicable to the general situation where none of the circles are congruent.

One usefull observation I can make is that any line which connects the centers of  any two circles is perpendicular to the line which connects the endpoints of the areas in common between the two circles.To be clear if you observe the above diagram $OO_1$ is always perpendicular to $AD$ .

That's the relevant part of my effort,now I am trying just to "add" some random line to see if i can stab at something usefull.

Comment: can you change circle AB such that A and D remain the same?

Comment: The condition you got is equivalent to the congruency of the three lines, as stated by [Cevas Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem)

Comment: @QuangHoang I know,but in fact I've got that condition assuming that these lines are collinear,so I've to prove it.

Comment: If the three centers are situated on the sides of the triangle, i.e. if the three circles are those whose diameters are the triangle's sides, then the three cevians meet at the triangle's orthocenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove that using the following :

> Let $O_1$ be the circle on which $A,F,D,C$ exist. Also, let $O_2$ be the circle on which $C,F,B$. Let $X$ be the intersection point between $AD$ and $CF$. And let $E'(\not =B)$ be the intersection point between $O_2$ and $BX$. Then, four points $E',A,B,D$ are on a circle.

This is because we have 
$$\text{$\triangle{CXE'}$ and $\triangle{BXF}$ are similar}$$
$$\text{$\triangle{CXD}$ and $\triangle{AXF}$ are similar}$$
$$\text{$\triangle{E'XA}$ and $\triangle{DXB}$ are similar}$$

Comment: How does that show that $E'$ is a point of intersection between two circles ?

Comment: @Nameless: A circle is uniquely determined by three distinct points (in this case $A,B,D$). So, we can say that $E'=E$.

Comment: Yes,but why do we need to prove that $E',A,B,D$ lie on a circle?Can't we just argue that if we extend $BX$ we will have a point of intersection with circle $O_2$ ?Also didn't we just prove that $E'$ is a point on circle $O_2$ ?How can we claim that it is also the point of intersection with  circle  $O_3 $?I am so confused...

Comment: Once you've proven that,how does it follow that E' is also a point of intersection wth $O_3$ ?

Comment: @Nameless: Let me explain my answer. First, let $E'$ be the intersection point between $O_2$ and $BX$. (We don't know yet if $E'$ exists on a circle (call this $O_3$) on which $A,B,D$ exist.) Then, we can say that $E',A,B,D$ lie on a circle (call this $O$). By the way, as I wrote, we can say that $O=O_3$. So, we can say that $E'$ is on $O_3$. It follows from this that $E'=E$. The result follows. I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay now it's clear .Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a well known theorem called the radical axis theorem.

Define the radical axis of two circles as the locus of points which has equal power with respect to both circles. ( Show that this locus is a line. 
To do this show this, take a point $P$ which has equal power with respect to both the circles and draw the tangents to both the circles from point $P$. From the right triangles so formed use the pythagorean theorem to deduce that the perpendicular from the point $P$ to the segment joining both the centres ($O_1O_2$) of the circles is always the same.)

Let $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2$ and $\Gamma_3$ be $3$ circles. Let $l_1$ be the radical axis of $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$, $l_2$ be the radical axis of $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_3$ and $l_3$ be the radical axis of $\Gamma_2$ and $\Gamma_3$. Let $R=l_1\cap{}l_2$ then $R$ has equal power with respect to all the three circles. This implies that $R\in{l_3}$. Thus $l_1,l_2$ and $l_3$ are concurrent.

Note that the radical axis of two intersecting circles is the line passing through the two intersection points.

Comment: I get it,thanks..I have still a little doubt about proving that there exists only one point $P$ on $O_1O_2$ such that $Pow(P,O_1)=Pow(P,O_2)$.Do you think it' better if I make a new question about that,or I just edit my question ?(The problem is that I get a contradiction in terms)

Comment: For more about the proof see here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Radical_axis

Comment: That's exactly where i am coming from,but some proofs are left to the reader...

Comment: There is a proof using coordinates over here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/radical-axis-of-2-circles/